# Convert string to int inside WHERE clause of SQLITE statment

Tags: sqlite, casting, where-clause

I want to achieve this:

`SELECT * FROM linkledger WHERE toInt(reputation) > 100;`

but the function toInt doesnt exist? Is there one?

I found this now but not working, which implies i have a more fundemental problem. **BECAUSE THIS IS CORRECT**

`SELECT * FROM linkledger WHERE cast(reputation AS INTEGER) > 100;`

Comment: What happens when you just omit `toInt`?

Comment: i think you can directly do `WHERE reputation > 100`

Comment: You have a problem because something is correct? What do you mean?

Comment: Well, what is your schema? What is `linkledger`? What is `reputation`?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use [**`CAST(reputation AS INTEGER)`**](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#castexpr).

Comment: cOrrect answer, I clearly have a more fundemental problem however.

Comment: What other problem do you have?

Comment: thanks @Tichodroma for editing my post. i am new here . it will help me in giving answer next time if you tell me is there any problem in giving link ? or any other thing that should not attach in the answer. thanks in advance

Comment: No, this kind of link is fine. You could add an example of how to use `CAST`.

Comment: The question says this as the keyword needn't be in uppercase, no?

Answer (score 2):

I will leave Anik Islam Abhi's answer as the correct one because it will apply in most cases but I just want it on record that I only managed to fix the problem by just switching the variable to int

`create table foo reputation int;`

And then insuring Ints were inserted... I'm not sure what was happening that the correct answer didnt solve my problem.

Comment: What was its type previously? This is almost certainly the issue but you never told us.

Comment: Yeah I said it in the question title. It was a String.

I tried having the engine cast for me, I tried to correct answer which i marked, and i even tried rounding the string. And also tried compairing the string number to a string number.

Comment: From [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast): _"To cast a string to a numeric value in numeric context, you normally do not have to do anything other than to use the string value as though it were a number"_.